# Thank you page not responsive, cant find root cause, java ,php, css conflict?

Tags: php, joomla

[thank you page](https://palmerstownpharmacy.ie/en/?option=com_virtuemart&view=pluginresponse&task=pluginresponsereceived&viewOnly=1&M_pm=6&cartId=KZ8Q01226&transStatus=Y)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQe9M.png)AFter installing new payment plugin on Joomla website ,the thank you page is not responsive, the mobile menu is displayed on top of the thank you page.

I used firefox developer tool to try to find root cause, its showing a ReferenceError: SqueezeBox is not defined , but I dont know where to start looking after that to find root cause.

I know the pages in joomla are produced by php files, how do I go about tracing which php files generated the html webpage?

Do I need to post more information?

Answer (score 0):

SqueezeBox is loaded by `modal.js` which in turn requires mootools to be loaded. Mootools should be enabled by default, but it ultimately depends on your template and any optimization plugins such as JCH Optimize, JQuery easy, my own Too Many Files...

Most likely your newest plugin addition makes use of SqueezeBox and you disabled its loading (intentionally or not). So either change to a plugin that uses a jQuery modal, or load mootools+modal